# Problem running a Python GUI application on Mac

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, pyinstaller

I've got a Python CLI tool that I'd like to wrap with the Gooey module to create a nice interface for my users. I'd also like to package the tool using PyInstaller to create a Max OSX app. This works and I can open the GUI app on my Mac, however, if I give the app to someone else they get an error dialog:

"myapp" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

I've tried a few command line options with PyInstaller, but still no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions or pointers that could help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Please refrain from signing your posts - the user card here is thought to be sufficient for that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to Apple locking down their hardware, which is both a good and a bad thing. In preferences you can go to the security tab and allow the application to run, but because I’m guessing its not a compiled executable and just a python script it could see it as malicious.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-a-mac-app-from-an-unidentified-developer-mh40616/mac This article might help.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/apple-cant-check-app-for-malicious-software-mchleab3a043/11.0/mac/11.0 Here is another article that states how to roughly do the same thing.

You could, however, sign the software yourself (although this is probably out of your reach) https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/, which allows you to just sign the software and not give people that warning.

But if all you want is to have people test the app without being suspicious, you can just override the settings for that.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, I'll dig into the links you provided and see where I get. :)